# Kill puma thread once request has been handled rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, puma

With `puma` the number of threads can be altered to handle multiple requests at the same time. But in case of Heroku, the database connections to postgres are limited.

To handle more requests we can increase the number of dynos, where each dyno has lets say by default 0:16 threads. In which case under load each dyno can make 16 connections to the database.

With rails `ActiveRecord` we can limit the number of database connections per rails worker process using this configuration:

```
Rails.application.config.after_initialize do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.disconnect!

  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
    config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env]
    config['reaping_frequency'] = ENV['DB_REAP_FREQ'] || 10 # seconds
    config['pool']              = ENV['DB_POOL']      || ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
  end
end
```

However with the db connection limit, if the number of dynos increase the connection limit is hit.

Is there any way to like kill a thread and close the database connection soon as the request has been served?

I've tried using `pgbouncer` as a `buildpack` but there are issues with prepared statements.

I'm currently on `rails 4.0.0` using `puma 2.7.1`.

Is there some event hook in puma whcih we can configure like this for when a request is complete?

```
on_worker_boot do
  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use cluster mode of puma if you use MRI. I suggest to setup 4 workers.

`puma -w 4`

If you use Jruby, you need to specify near 20 threads. But it should not be more then number of allowed connections to the DB.

`puma -t 20:20`

More info:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#thread-safety

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections#maximum-database-connections